# Table tr height fixed not working for Chrome

Tags: html, css, height, tablerow

Setting fixed height on a `<tr>` in a table is not working in Chrome.

If you apply `height: 90%`, it will change to 100%. The remaining 10% are invisible.

But it works in IE.

Why doesn't it work in Chrome?

```
<table style = "height:100%">
  <tr style = "height:20px"></tr>
  <tr style = "height:90%"></tr>
  <tr style = "height:20px"></tr>
  <tr style = "height:10%"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try to add css as: `body,html{height:100%;}`

Comment: Welcome to CSS!

Comment: Are you trying to put a height of 100% + 40px in 100%? That won't work. Something's going to break.

Answer (score 1):

aahhhh, yes, browser inconsistancies. We've been dealing with this ever since Netscape wasn't the only browser to use (aka since the Internet went public).

The easiest way to deal with this seems to be through CSS. Add this to the top of your CSS page (below `@charset "UTF-8";`):

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  )
```

Without it, everything on IE generally sits about 8 pixels lower than on any other browser. Humankind knows no reason why...